# rspec testing for a console command output

Tags: rspec, sh, fastlane

I have the following snippet code in ruby

```
lizard_cli_version = Gem::Version.new(`lizard --version`.scan(/(?:\d+\.?){3}/).first)
required_version = Gem::Version.new(Fastlane::Lizard::CLI_VERSION)
if lizard_cli_version < required_version
  UI.user_error!("Your lizard version is outdated, please upgrade to at least version #{Fastlane::Sentry::CLI_VERSION} and start your lane again!")
end
```

I want to test it using the following RSpec but it is not working

```
context "there is no lizard installed" do
  it "states lizard is needed and how to install" do
    allow(FastlaneCore::UI).to receive(:user_error)
    expect(FastlaneCore::UI).to receive(:user_error).with(/Your lizard version is outdated/)

    expect(Fastlane::Actions).to receive(:sh).and_raise("1.14.1")
    expect(FastlaneCore::UI).to receive(:user_error!)

    expect do
      Fastlane::FastFile.new.parse("lane :test do
        lizard
      end").runner.execute(:test)
    end.to raise_error(/Your lizard version is outdated/)
  end
end
```

this is the output

```
Failures:

  1) Fastlane::Actions::LizardAction Lizard there is no lizard installed states lizard is needed and how to install
     Failure/Error: expect(FastlaneCore::UI).to receive(:user_error).with(/You have to install lizard using/)

       (FastlaneCore::UI (class)).user_error(/Your lizard version is outdated/)
           expected: 1 time with arguments: (/Your lizard version is outdated/)
           received: 0 times
     # ./spec/lizard_spec.rb:15:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.48 seconds (files took 3.55 seconds to load)
17 examples, 1 failure
```

Does anybody have any suggestion how to make this work?

Comment: What response do you get when you run your test? Also, please show the class and method that contains the snippet of code that generates the error.

Answer (score 3):

Is not easy with this information to know what is the problem, but maybe it could be this in this line...

```
expect(Fastlane::Actions).to receive(:sh).and_raise("1.14.1")
```

Maybe what you want is to use `and_return` instead of `and_raise`...

```
expect(Fastlane::Actions).to receive(:sh).and_return("1.14.1")
```

And in your code use `Fastlane::Actions.sh` to get the `lizard --version` ...

```
Gem::Version.new(Fastlane::Actions.sh("lizard --version").scan(/(?:\d+\.?){3}/).first)
```

Comment: Failures:

  1) Fastlane::Actions::LizardAction Lizard Lizard version 1.14.1 installed states lizard need to upgrade to at least 1.14.10
     Failure/Error:
       expect do
         Fastlane::FastFile.new.parse("lane :test do
           lizard
         end").runner.execute(:test)
       end.to raise_error(/Your lizard version is outdated/)
     
       expected /Your lizard version is outdated/ but nothing was raised
     # ./spec/lizard_spec.rb:20:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.41 seconds (files took 3.73 seconds to load)

Comment: You should use `Actions.sh` to get the "lizard version" (rather than back ticks) so that you can perform the expect as outlined by Benito.

Comment: I added one more line to the answer with the comment of @LyndseyFerguson